# SQLAlchemy ORM: constant column value on select / update / insert

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'm wrapping an existing DB with a pre-defined (and very messy) schema in an SQLAlchemy-based Pythonic API. To clarify: the schema is a given and I am trying to wrap it in a slightly cleaner API, and cannot modify it.

I have some tables that contain a lot of data that I do not care about, and can contain some columns which should always contain the same value when selecting / inserting / updating.

For example:

```
+-------+--------+-------------+------------+
| id    | type   | name        | date       |
+-------+--------+-------------+------------+
| 1     | foo    | Entry 1     | 2020-01-01 |
| 2     | foo    | Entry 2     | 2020-01-02 |
| 3     | foo    | Entry 5     | 2020-01-03 |
| 4     | foo    | Other thing | 2020-01-04 |
+-------+--------+-------------+------------+
```

In this table, for all intents and purposes of my code, `type` should *always* be `'foo'`. I need to always have `WHERE type = 'foo'` when selecting, updating or inserting. There may be other values, but I want to ignore them in my code.

Is there a way to define such a "constant" / "hidden" column in SQLAlchemy's declarative API?

I know I can probably achieve this with `polymorphic_identity` and friends, but:

- AFAIK this capability is limited to a single column per class, and I need this on more than one column
- There really isn't an inheritance structure here, just garbage I want to ignore, and I do not care about other cases that much.

Is there a way to do this with SQLAlchemy, or should I fall back to polymorphism?

Comment: Can you create a view like `CREATE VIEW foo_customer AS SELECT * FROM customer WHERE type='foo'` and then base your ORM object on that?

Comment: @GordThompson Good suggestion, but unfortunately no, I cannot change the schema or create views.